# How to change the labelling of connected components in connectedComponetsWithStats opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am building an OCR system for malayalam. I am using cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats function for character segmentation.

[Here is the sample word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Jc4.png)

I want the connected components to be labeled from left to right i.e., based on x coordinate. But the function is labeling the connected components according to y coordinate.

Here is the dictionary of labeled connected components with (x,y,w,h). I want the connected components to be labeled from left to right i.e., in the increasing order of x coordinate

```
{1: [287, 4, 19, 12], 2: [196, 19, 73, 33], 3: [276, 19, 29, 33], 4: [12, 20, 65, 34], 5: [102, 20, 57, 33], 6: [164, 20, 29, 34], 7: [80, 21, 16, 50], 8: [311, 45, 10, 16]}
```

Is  there any way to change ?

Comment: You can sort the connected components by sorting the first value in every key of the dictionary.

Comment: +1 for Jeru, you should write a function to sort your values based on y, I don't think there is any option in connectedComponentsWithStats which would do that